# AngularJS : Replicate div on click of button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to replicate the text fields(div) present in image every time the user click on '+' button.[image: Replicate div]

Comment: add more information of what you're trying to do

Comment: Have you tried anything ? You can write a `directive` that replicate the respective `div`

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your question properly , pls refer the below code .

**Template**

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input type="text" placeholder="name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="email">
        <button ng-click="add()">+</button>
        <p>Some text some text some text</p>   
   </div> 
</div>
```

**controller**

```
var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);

app.controller('myCtrl',["$scope",function($scope){

    $scope.items = [{}];

    $scope.add = function(){
       $scope.items.push({});
    }

}]);
```

refer:  https://jsfiddle.net/ftzebggn/

Comment: How do I access the all input field content in my controller ?

Comment: @chiragshah when do u need the all the input field values ,

Comment: on click of button outside ng-repeat div

Comment: @chiragshah Its better to use directive for this , plz see the update fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ftzebggn/2/

Comment: How do I create dynamic ng-model for each  input field using $index. Something like <input type="text" placeholder="name" ng-model="name_{{$index}}">