# Update scope variable dynamically. Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following:

**html**

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-controller="firstController">
    <ul id="conversation">
        <li ng-repeat="msg in messages">{{msg}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**js**

```
var messages = [];
//Messages is updated everytime a message is sent.

var firstController = function($scope) {
    $scope.messages = messages;
}

app.controller("firstController", firstController);
```

I have a button that updates the global javascript messages variable. I need to update the $scope messages variable everytime my button is clicked. My controller only runs when the page first loads.
How can I update $scope variables?

Comment: Can you show your code where you update `$scope.messages`, is it inside `setTimeout` or is it in HTML?

Comment: @JarekKulikowski I show it. I update $scope.messages inside the firstController function.

Comment: Why do you need to handle the button click outside of the angularjs app? Why can't using [`ngClick`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)?

Comment: @StanislavKvitash, what do you mean.

Comment: You wrote `everytime my button is clicked` - how does this code look like? Why can't you handle click event inside your `firstController` using [`ngClick`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) directive?

Comment: Angularjs is a framework which is providing two way data binding and other watching features. You already using angular in your project and why can't you avoid global message variable, you could directly use the $scope.message variable to hold the data and which you can update just using ng-click directive.

Comment: @M.Nar Can you please check this link, it contains some good code for doing something similar to what you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33210478/angularjs-replicate-div-on-click-of-button

Answer (score 0):

As it was suggested, you can use `ng-click` to `invoke` a function in the controller whenever the button is clicked. You can update the `messages array` within the function.

Below is a code example on how to do this. You can check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/81bv9ycs/) to see it in action.

```
<div id="appContainer" ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
  <button ng-click="updateMessages();">Click Me</button>
    <div ng-repeat="msg in messages">
      <label>{{msg}}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.messages = [];
    $scope.updateMessages = function() {
    $scope.messages.push('Date is: ' + new Date().toString());
  };
}]);
```